# What are the odds of 3 out of 8 people sharing the same birthday?

Tags: statistics, birthday

I work on a team of 8 people. Three share the same birthday. I'm no mathematician but I imagine the odds are literally astronomical in measure.
A figure in this instance may be meaningless to me. Does the answer give a clue to how many times in human history has this likely happened?
Could we be the 1st or is this more likely than common sense assumes.

Comment: Well it's small but not as small as you would think. For example there is usually more than $50%$ chance two student in the same classroom (with more than 23 students) share the same birthday.

Comment: That's hard to believe with common sense thinking but I accept it and have witnessed it several times.  But 3 out of 8 is on an entirely different scale.

Comment: Definitely not astronomical.  Even with only three people, the probability is $1/365^2 \approx 7.5\times 10^{-6}$.  So about one in 100,000 teams of that size will have a triple birthday.  With eight people, it's maybe 50x greater, so about one in 2,000 eight-person teams will experience this.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Lelouch:  MathJax hint:  to get a percent sign you need to escape it with a backslash, so use 50\% to get $50\%$

Comment: If you have seen it once it is much more probable you will see it again because you tend to be in teams with the same people over again.  These correlations are easy to overlook.

Answer (score 2):

The chance of a particular three people sharing a particular birthday is $\frac 1{365^3}$.  If we ignore the chance four people will share a birthday or two triplets will exist, which will cause overcounting, we can multiply by the ${8 \choose 3}=56$ ways to select three people and $365$ birthdays we could choose, leaving $\frac {56}{365^2}\approx 0.00042$ or $1$ in about $2380$.  Not such a low chance at all.

Comment: I'm certainly surprised it could happen that often.

Comment: mjqxxx.  50 X 1 in 100,000 is greater than 1 in 2,000, isn't it?

Comment: I highly recommend David J. Hand's ***The Improbability Principle: Why Coincidences, Miracles, and Rare Events Happen Every Day***.  One in a million events happen *ALL THE TIME*... they *have* to.

Comment: @bobeyt6:  Huh?  What is your link supposed to mean?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork oops typo. [Fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_truly_large_numbers)